# Using Complex Collection with c:foreach in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, collections, jstl, el

If I have this code in a .java file

```
for (int i = 0; i < person.getFamilyMembers().get(0).getCount(); i++) {
    out.println(person.getFamilyMembers().get(0).getMember().get(i).getLastName()
        + "<br />");
}
```

Where `getFamilyMembers()` returns an `ArrayList<FamilyMembers>` and `getCount()` returns and int

How do I go about putting this in a JSP with JSTL/EL? I know how to do a foreach on a simple Collection, but this is obviously more involved.

Thanks

Comment: I guess `getMember` is another `ArrayList`, right? If it has a different size than `getfamilyMembers()` you will get an exception.

Comment: It works fine in java, just trying to get it out of a scriplet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your purpose is display the `LastName` of each `Member` of the first `FamilyMember` of the `Person`, I would just go with:

```
<c:forEach var="m" items="${person.familyMembers[0].member}">
    ${m.lastName}
</c:forEach>
```